# DaVinci Resolve ignores MOV (QuickTime) metadata

Tags: davinci-resolve, linux

When importing MOV files on Linux, DaVinci Resolve seems to use only modification date from filesystem, but completely ignores metadata from movie file:

[image: metadata in davinci resolve]

Using e.g. `exiftool` we can fetch date information which seems to be ignored:

```
$ exiftool -time:all -G1 -a -s DSC_0461.MOV
[System]        FileModifyDate                  : 2020:10:17 14:36:06+02:00
[System]        FileAccessDate                  : 2020:10:17 14:36:10+02:00
[System]        FileInodeChangeDate             : 2020:10:17 14:36:06+02:00
[QuickTime]     CreateDate                      : 2018:12:12 22:19:19
[QuickTime]     ModifyDate                      : 2018:12:12 22:19:20
[Track1]        TrackCreateDate                 : 2018:12:12 22:19:20
[Track1]        TrackModifyDate                 : 2018:12:12 22:19:20
[Track1]        MediaCreateDate                 : 2018:12:12 22:19:20
[Track1]        MediaModifyDate                 : 2018:12:12 22:19:20
[Track2]        TrackCreateDate                 : 2018:12:12 22:19:20
[Track2]        TrackModifyDate                 : 2018:12:12 22:19:20
[Track2]        MediaCreateDate                 : 2018:12:12 22:19:20
[Track2]        MediaModifyDate                 : 2018:12:12 22:19:20
[ItemList]      ContentCreateDate               : 2018:12:12 22:19:19
[UserData]      DateTimeOriginal                : 2018:12:12 22:19:19
[XMP-exif]      DateTimeOriginal                : 2018:12:12 22:19:19
```

Any idea which metadata fields are being recognized by DaVinci Resolve 16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a simple [LUA script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deric/DaVinciResolve-metadata/main/com.deric.ExifMetadata/EXIF-metadata.lua) extension that can be executed from Workspace > Scripts toolbar after copying the script to `{resolve directory}/Fusion/Scripts/Comp`. Here's t[he source code](https://github.com/deric/DaVinciResolve-metadata). Currently the number of EXIF fields is limited, but can be easily extended.

The script tries to match media files from Media Storage with media clips in Project's Media Pool. EXIF data are parsed using [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/). Currently should work on Linux/Mac OS, but can be easily ported to Windows.

[image: EXIF synchronization tool]